# Unresolved reference: createNotificationChannel

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, notifications, location

Unable to solve this error. I had previously build this app, and was working fine. But now gives me this error. Anyone any idea how to solve this?

```
Task :location:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\flutter_windows_2.10.2-stable\flutter\.pub-
cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\location-
4.4.0\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocationService.kt: (73, 33): 
Unresolved reference: createNotificationChannel
```

FlutterLocationService.kt file:

```
private fun updateChannel(channelName: String) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        ).apply {
            lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        }
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

clean and rebuild your project
Try -

Build -> Clean Project